# Sampling from a Rand Effects GLMM in R

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, random-effects-model, glmm, covariance-matrix

I am needing to learn how to create and sample from a baseline category logit random effects model in R.

I have 5 categories, not fully ordered..  I need to generate about 600 simulated response vectors.  Each vector needs to contain 16 multinomial trials, with teh possible responses being one of the five categories above.

I have tried playing around with a few of the GLMM packages in R, but I am unsure if I am using them correctly or even what my input covariance matrix needs to be.

I am still new to the statistics world (I am coming over from a math program), so I apologize if my language is not clear.  Please feel free to ask any questions for clarification.